# What is the compactification of $y=e^x$ in $\mathbb P_{\mathbb C}^2$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Denote the curve $V(y-e^x)\subset \mathbb A_{\mathbb C}^2$ by X, and consider its closure $\bar X$ in $\mathbb P_{\mathbb C}^2$. By GAGA, we know $\bar X$ is algebraic. I think this is amazing. I want to ask what is the algebraic equation of $\bar X$?

Comment: $0$, as $\overline{X}$ is the whole space: any polynomial vanishing on $X$ is zero, as proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2645213/non-algebraic-set-of-countably-infinite-set-of-points). I think this may be enough for this to be a duplicate - what do you think?

Comment: Of course zariski closure is the whole space. But I meant to consider euclidean topology while taking closure. I wonder is it still the case?

Comment: Keep in mind that the compactification in the classical topology (in this case) is not an analytic subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I claim the closure in the Euclidean topology is
$$\overline X:=\{(x:e^x:1):x\in\mathbb C\}\cup\{(x:y:0):(x:y)\in\mathbb P^1\}.$$
Indeed, for any $x\in\mathbb C$, all $(x+2\pi in:e^x:1)\in\mathbb C$, so the closure contains $(1:0:0)$, the limit as $n\to\infty$. Moreover, the limit of $(x:e^x:1)$ as $x\in\mathbb R$ goes to infinity is $(0:1:0)$, so $(0:1:0)\in\overline X$.

Finally, we hope to find points $x_n\in\mathbb C$ such that $(x_n:e^{x_n}:1)$ converges to $(y:1:0)$, i.e., $x_ne^{-x_n}$ converges to $y$. But such a sequence $x_n$ exists, since $xe^{-x}$ is a holomorphic function on $\mathbb C$ so by Picard's great theorem tells us that $xe^{-x}=y$ has an infinite set of solutions where necessarily $|x_n|\to\infty$.

Thus $\overline X$ is just isomorphic to $\mathbb P^1\sqcup\mathbb P^1/(\infty\sim \infty)$