What is the Zariski closure of $X = V(y = e^{x}) \subseteq \mathbb{C}^{2}$
My attempt: assume $X \subseteq V(f_{1}, \dots, f_{n})$, where $f_{i} \in \mathbb{C}[x, y]$. Consider embedding $\mathbb{C}[x, y]$ into $\mathbb{C}[[x, y]]$. For any $(a, b) \in X$, we have $b = \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} \frac{a^{n}}{n!}$. For $f_{j}$, it is obvious that it cannot only contain $x$ or $y$. So when $a$ and $b$ are substituted into $f_{m}$, an infinite term of $a$ cannot be eliminated, which means $f_{m} = 0$. So we have the Zariski closure of $X$ is $\mathbb{C}^{2}$. 
I feel that my proof is not rigorous and may even be incorrect. Is there any correct method to calculate this question? Any response would be greatly appreciated.

You’re right. Although, the question has been asked before, and therefore this will be marked as duplicate. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2645213/non-algebraic-set-of-countably-infinite-set-of-points

I guess the title should state $y = e^x$ (or something similar), otherwise you are just considering a line, which is algebraic.
